# How to share variables between different CMake files

Tags: cmake

How do I share variables between different CMake files, and I show the following examples to illustrate my question:

#### Main

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(test)
set(Var3 "Global variable")

add_subdirectory(${test_SOURCE_DIR}/exe)
add_subdirectory(${test_SOURCE_DIR}/dll)
```

#### EXE file

```
set(Var1 "this is variable 1")
set(Var1 ${Var1} " added to varible 1")
message(STATUS ${Var1})
```

#### DLL file

```
set(Var2 "this is variable 2")
message(STATUS ${Var2})
message(STATUS ${Var1})
message(STATUS ${Var3})
```

In this example, Var3 can be seen in the CMake files of `exe` and `dll` as it is defined in `Main`. However, Var1, which is defined in `exe`, will not be observed in `dll`. I was just curious: is there a way to make Var1 defined in `exe` observable in `dll`?

Comment: One day I'm tired of visibility tricks and made some [extensions](https://github.com/ruslo/sugar/wiki/Collecting-sources)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Beside what Tadeusz correctly said, you can make a variable visible at any level (not just one up!) by using

```
set(Var1 "This is variable 1" CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

The variable will be available for all the CMake instructions that follow that instruction, so for example it won't be available for a sister directory that is added before the directory where this variable is defined.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for `.. CACHE INTERNAL "")`. This now caches the values, and hence the values can be validated in the "CMakefiles" generated, as well, as when the value is attempted to be logged in the CMakeLists.txt, using "STATUS", in different project (specially, in case of dependent sub-projects".

Answer (score 19):

The scopes of variable visibility form a tree. The CMakeFiles.txt files added with `add_subdirectory` have access to the variables defined in themselves, and in the parent scope (the toplevel global scope in your example).

You can export a variable one level up using:

```
set(Var1 "This is variable 1" PARENT_SCOPE)
```