# cmake use header file sibling subproject

Tags: cmake, dependencies, header-files

It is some time I'm googleing the net but I didn't found a way for solve this problem.

I'm doing  a redesign of the source code I use for my project.
I would like to have them in this way:

```
/RootProject
|
|---Module 1
|---Module 2
|---Module 3
|---etc.
```

Every module is made by one or more source file and relative header file.
Every module produce a shared library. Sometimes there are dependencies in libraries,
as example Module 2 depends on Module 1, I would like that cmake automagically handle the header file. I'm trying different combinations of add_directory, PARENT SCOPE etc but I didn't found yet a simple way for having this done. 
How do you handle this situation
thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for future readers... I found this that cover the same topic and for me is accepted.
[CMake and finding other projects and their dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398937/cmake-and-finding-other-projects-and-their-dependencies)