# Cmake Linking Shared Library: "No such file or directory" when include a header file from library

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

I am learning to build a library using CMake. The code structure for building library is like below:

```
include:  
   Test.hpp       
   ITest.hpp     // interface
src:
   Test.cpp
   ITest.cpp
```

In CMakeLists.txt, the sentences I used to build library is :

```
file(GLOB SRC_LIST "src/iTest.cpp" "src/Test.cpp" "include/Test.hpp"
        "include/iTest.hpp"  "include/deadreckoning.hpp")
add_library(test SHARED ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries( test ${OpenCV_LIBS})  // link opencv libs to libtest.so
```

Then I wrote another test file (main.cpp), copy and paste the library under the same directory, link library and call functions inside the library.
This CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(myapp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread -O3 -Wall -ftree-vectorize -ffast-math -funroll-loops")

add_executable(myapp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myapp "/home/labUser/test_lib/libtest.so")
```

The main.cpp compiles and runs succussfully if I don't include the header files inside the library:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

But when I include the header file `#include "ITest.hpp"`, it has error:

```
fatal error: iTest.hpp: No such file or directory
  #include "iTest.hpp"   
compilation terminated.
```

I don't understand why it happens. I think I have already linked the library successfully because when I run main.cpp without including header file, it doesn't give any "linking" error. And I think apparently the header files are inside the library. Why I can't include it? Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here.

**Propagating headers to users of your target:**

Whilst you've added the include file to your library target, you need to let *consumers* of your library target know how to find the header.

As such, when your app `myapp` links against your library target `test`, you need to tell cmake to add `./include` to `myapp's` include search path.

There is a special cmake variable, [`${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html) which resolves to the path to the directory in which the current `CMakeLists.txt` being processed is.

In your instance, that is the parent folder of both `src` and `include`.

```
./                    <-- ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} is this directory
+--- CMakeLists.txt
+--- src/
|    +---Test.cpp
|    +---ITest.cpp
+--- include/
     +---Test.hpp
     +---ITest.hpp
```

In order to tell cmake to add a path to its include search path you use [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html)

For this the path will then be `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include`

So the syntax you'd be looking for is:

```
target_include_directories(test PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include)
```

Note that this means you don't have to add `"include/iTest.hpp"` and `"include/Test.hpp"` to your `SRC_LIST` glob, as the compiler will be able to find them from the above `target_include_directories`

**Linking to your test library:**

Now that you've created your library and added the include directories, to actually *use it* in your app, you should again use `target_link_libraries`, but don't specify the path to the generated `.so` file, instead refer to the name of the library target you created, `test`

```
target_link_libraries(myapp test)
```

Now `myapp` will know how to find `Test.hpp` because it will get that information from the "dependency link" you've created between `myapp` and `test`

As such, assuming the following directory structure, the following CMakeLists.txt files may work

```
src/
+--- library/
|    +--- < sources for your shared library >
+--- app/
     +--- < sources for your application >
```

**`src/CMakeLists.txt`**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(myapp)

add_subdirectory(library)
add_subdirectory(app)
```

**`src/library/CMakeLists.txt`**

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} 
    -std=c++11 
    -pthread 
    -O3 
    -Wall 
    -ftree-vectorize 
    -ffast-math 
    -funroll-loops")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_library(test SHARED "src/iTest.cpp src/Test.cpp")
target_link_libraries(test ${OpenCV_LIBS})  // link opencv libs to libtest.so
target_include_directories(test PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include)
```

**`src/app/CMakeLists.txt`**

```
add_executable(myapp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myapp test)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried to modify the library CMakeLists but I got the error when I compile: target_include_directories called with invalid arguments   Do you know why? Do I need to specify where ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} is?

Comment: @KathyLee looks like you're using an old version of cmake. Are you able to upgrade to a newer version? (cmake 2.8 is very old)

Comment: @KathyLee if you can't upgrade, try use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` instead, I believe this variable exists in 2.8

Comment: @KathyLee for something this small you could just add `include_directories(include)`

Comment: @afakih that's not recommended, and for someone trying to learn cmake, teaching best practice is probably a good idea

Comment: @SteveLorimer I have updated cmake to 3.2 but both commands fail. So I just copy-paste the usage of target_include_directories from https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_include_directories.html and it works! Thank you!   One more question, can I use this library in another program? Since in your answer, you include both "test" library and "myapp" binary in same CMakeLists.txt. However, I would like to call this library in another program using another CMakeLists.txt under different directory. I used the code above but still cannot find header file.  How can I change CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: @KathyLee apologies, I forgot the `PUBLIC` keyword in `target_include_directories`. I've updated the answer. In order to pull in the `CMakeLists.txt` file in which your `test` library is defined, add `add_subdirectory(XXX)` to your `myapp` `CMakeLists.txt` file, where XXX is the directory in which the `test` `CMakeLists.txt` file is located

Comment: @KathyLee updated the answer with a directory and CMakeLists layout which might help

Comment: @SteveLorimer  Thank you Steve! Your answer runs successfully! But this answer is to run library and app "at the same time" if compile src/CMakeLists.txt. Is it possible that I run the library first and save the library under one directory and then I run app with linking the lib? For example, after running the answer above, libtest.so is located in src/build/library. If I wrote another stand-alone app outside src, how can I link it to the library and let this app find all included header file?

Comment: @SteveLorimer I found out a way to deal with my latest question. Maybe in CMakeLists.txt, I can use `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`  to include the header files in library. Then `add_executable` and `target_link_libraries(myNewApp /home/labUser/Downloads/src/build/library/libmyLib.so")`        I hope this is a correct way to use the library. Thanks!

Comment: @KathyLee Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175318/cmake-how-to-build-external-projects-and-include-their-targets) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398937/cmake-and-finding-other-projects-and-their-dependencies) for help with your latest request

Comment: @SteveLorimer Thanks!