# Link one project to another CMAKE

Tags: cmake

I am building a project which contains lots of sub projects. for example as ...

```
LibA (build as shared library)

LibB (depends on LibA & build as shared library)

AppB (depends on LinB)
```

Directory structure (Which I want) is as ...

```
bin/
output/
src/libA/
src/libB/
src/appB/
```

Each of sub projects (LibA, LibB & AppB) has their own CMakeLists.txt file.

I want ..

```
1. Build LibA as shared library (I know how to do it)

2. Build LibB as shared library with linking of LibA (Don't Know how to do)
   Explanation: When I start building LibB, 
                LibA build first and 
                ready to link for LibB 
                when LibB ready to finish

3. Build AppB : If I start building AppB, 
                LibA build first and 
                LibB build after and
                both linked to AppB
```

Now I know classic way, build separately LibA & LibB and supplied path of lib and include to AppB. But I want to build them at once like

```
  Build LibA 
  Build LibB (if LibA is already build then ignore, else build LibA)
  Build AppB (if LibA, LibB are already build then ignore, else build them)
```

**What I want**

- How can I achieve such behavior using CMAKE ?
- It should be cross platform
- Simple enough to include many more sub projects

Comment: One way is to add a `CMakeLists.txt` file at the top level directory to call `add_subdirectory()` on each of the projects you wish to pull in. I suggest you review this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398937/cmake-and-finding-other-projects-and-their-dependencies?rq=1).

Answer (score 7):

Here is one solution. You can use a top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file to tie all the projects together. So in your directory structure, this would be placed here:

```
bin/
output/
src/libA/
src/libB/
src/appB/
CMakeLists.txt    <--- Top-level CMakeLists.txt
```

Your top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file (as a sibling to the `src` directory) could look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

# Add your dependencies in the order you want them to build.
add_subdirectory(src/libA)
add_subdirectory(src/libB)
add_subdirectory(src/appB)
```

With each of the `src` directories having their own `CMakeLists.txt` file, here's an example of each of these individually.

You can set up LibA as a shared library with CMake with the `CMakeLists.txt` file in `src/libA`:

```
project(LibA_Project)
add_library(LibA SHARED sourceA.cpp  ... more sources here ...)
```

Next, CMake will traverse to the `src/libB` directory to configure LibB. Here is what the `src/libB/CMakeLists.txt` file could look like:

```
project(LibB_Project)
# Create a shared library for LibB as well.
add_library(LibB SHARED sourceB.cpp  ... more sources here ...)

# Link LibA to LibB as a dependency.
target_link_libraries(LibB LibA)
```

Finally, CMake will go to the `src/appB` directory. Here is that `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
project(AppB_Project)
# Create the executable AppB.
add_executable(AppB main.cpp ... more sources here ...)

# Link LibA and LibB to AppB as dependencies.
target_link_libraries(AppB LibA LibB)
```

This approach can easily be expanded to include more sub-projects (e.g. LibC, LibD, AppE, etc) if necessary.

Comment: This approach doesn't allow to build sub projects independenty.