# Internal dependencies with cmake in a large project

Tags: cmake

I have a project with multiple libraries which have dependencies between them.
It looks similar to this:

```
project
+ libs
| + lib1
| + lib2
| + lib3
+ apps
| + app1
| + app2
```

I have dependencies between different targets. For example, `lib2` depends on `lib1` and `lib3` depends on `lib2` (note transitive dependency here). Apps mostly depends on arbitrary number of libs.

I would like to have a `CMakeLists.txt` in the project root and in each library and application folder.

I assume that in the main `CMakeLists.txt` I will use `add_subdirectory()` to include other `CMakeLists.txt` files but I'm not sure what is the best practice to reflect dependencies between different targets (library on other libraries and application on libraries) since they reside on the same level. In other words I would like to know how `CMakeLists.txt` for `lib2` and `lib3` could look like.

**Update:**

I managed to find a potential solution: people suggest to use `add_dependencies(lib1 lib2)`. Should this be specified before all the `add_subdirectory()`?

Comment: `target_link_libraries` works even for libraries created on the same level. Not sure what is a problem. E.g. inside `libs/lib2/CMakeLists.txt` you could call `target_link_libraries(lib2 PUBLIC lib3)`. This would work even if main `CMakeLists.txt` firstly calls `add_subdirectory(libs/lib2)` and then `add_subdirectory(libs/lib3)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I know that `CMakeLists.txt` added with `add_subfolder()` is executed in a new context so I would expect that it will not know about other libraries that are added this way in root `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: `what is the best practice` There is only one thing you can do: just link the libraries normally, there is no best practice, a normal practice. `how CMakeLists.txt for lib2 and lib3 could look like.` Just write it, it will look completely normally. You can browse github for some big cmake projects, if you want to. `it will not know about other librarie` Well, what else can we offer than your expectancy is not valid? Don't trust me - write it and test it out. When you have _specific_ program with your cmake config, then come back and ask a specific question to your cmake configuration.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry, my mistake - I'm pretty new to cmake stuff. Thank you for correcting me, will update the post

Comment: Solution is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398937/cmake-and-finding-other-projects-and-their-dependencies/16404000